# Items around circle with higher angles

Tags: javascript, jquery, geometry

I am creating circle navigation with a selected item. When user click on any item it will move to certain point defined. All is working well except when you keep on click items than there is point comes when animation behaves differently and items moves in 360 degree circle and its get reset until you repeat the scenario , I want it smooth like the first time like how many time user clicks on item it should move smoothly.

Code [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/3ob6m8qh/42/) Once you click on items than you will see that behaviour

```
// rotate circle functions
var p = $(".cirlec-slider-bg");
$(".cirlec-slider-bg .f-courses").clone().appendTo(p);

var a = -($('.cirlec-slider-bg').width() / 2);
var b = $('.cirlec-slider-bg .f-courses').length;
var c = 360 / b;
rotateCircle(c, 'domReady');

$(".cirlec-slider-bg").on("click", ".f-courses", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {} else {
        $('.cirlec-slider-bg .f-courses').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var dataAngle = parseInt($(this).attr('data-angle'));
        var maxangle = 90 - dataAngle;


        rotateCircle(maxangle, 'onitemClick')
    }

});

function rotateCircle(maxangle, type) {
    $('.cirlec-slider-bg .f-courses').each(function(index) {

        if (type == 'onitemClick') {
            var maxAngle = maxangle;
            var dataAngle2 = parseInt($(this).attr('data-angle'));
            var maxangle2 = dataAngle2 + maxAngle;
            var d = (index) * c;
        }
        if (type == 'domReady') {
            var maxAngle = maxangle;
            var maxangle2 = (index) * maxAngle;
        }

        var m = [
            "translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(", -90, "deg) translateY(" + 100 + "px) rotate(", 90, "deg)"
        ];
        m[1] = maxangle2;
        m[3] = 0 - maxangle2;
        $(this).css({
            "transform": m.join("")
        });

        $(this).attr('data-angle', maxangle2);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing the value of `dataAngle` in the click handler shows that it sometimes exceeds the allowed range of `[0, 180]` - it can become negative or greater than 360.

The remedy was to add the following line after retrieving `dataAngle`:

```
dataAngle -= Math.floor(dataAngle / 360.0) * 360;
```

(Note that this is not the same as `dataAngle % 360`)

[Fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/of29wkL1/1)

Comment: Thank you I was trying to use that Math.PI function

Comment: @Hushme CSS uses degrees so I don't know why `Math.PI` would be useful?

Comment: that was mistake, i made this all myself and stuck on simple thing how stupid is I am

Comment: sometimes you stuck on simple thing that is a proof

Comment: @Hushme "stupid"? On the contrary I think this widget is quite cool.

Comment: Not until you helped me out, due to these line of code it was totally useless and buggy